# How to enable buttons

Tags: flutter, button, disable

In one of my Flutter app pages, I want to disable the `next` button at first. If the user enters any new value in the textfield, I want to enable `next` button. Here is my code, but the `next` button stays disabled no matter what. How can I enable the `next` button when a user enters a value? [image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool btnenabled = false;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text('Address'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
             .....
            TextFormField(
          onChanged: (newValue) {
              _currentaddress = '$addressJSON' + newValue;
              if (newValue.length > 0) {
                setState(() {
                  btnenabled = true;
                });
              }
            }),
            TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue[700], primary: Colors.white),
                child: Text('next',
                    ),
                onPressed: btnenabled == true
                    ? () => Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Summary()))
                    : null)
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
You can move `bool btnenabled = false;` out of `Widget build` 
change from

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool btnenabled = false;
```

to

```
bool btnenabled = false;
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool btnenabled = false;
  String _currentaddress = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text('Address'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(onChanged: (newValue) {
            _currentaddress = 'addressJSON' + newValue;
            if (newValue.length > 0) {
              setState(() {
                btnenabled = true;
              });
            }
          }),
          TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue[700], primary: Colors.white),
              child: Text(
                'next',
              ),
              onPressed: btnenabled == true
                  ? () => Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Summary()))
                  : null)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Summary extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Summary");
  }
}
```